# Handle an event of a control defined on another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I have a form declared as s property `WithEvents`. If I add `Handles formServers.FormClosing` to a `Sub` declaration it works fine, but when I want to handle an event of a control within `formServers` I get the following error -

> 'Handles' in classes must specify a 'WithEvents' variable.

How do I correctly set this up? Thanks.

```
Private WithEvents formServers As New formServers    

Private Sub txtServers_Closing(ByVal Sender As Object,
                                ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles formServers.txtServers.LostFocus

    Me.SetServers()

    If Me.ServersError Then
        Dim Ex As New Exception("Error validating Servers.")
        Dim ErrorForm = New formError(Ex, 101)
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do are not specifying `WithEvents` on the `TextBox`.  Rather, you are specifying `WithEvents` on the `Form`.  You can only use `Handles` on variables which you have declared *directly* with the `WithEvents` keyword.  With the `WithEvents` being on the form, you will only be able to use `Handles` to handle events that are raised directly by the form itself.  You will not be able to do so for events raised by any of its controls.

You can fix this in one of two ways.  Either you can use `AddHandler` to register your event handler (rather than using the `Handles` keyword), or you can create a `TextBox` variable `WithEvents` and then set it to the appropriate `TextBox` object on the form, like this.

```
Private formInstance As New FormServers 
Private WithEvents txtServers As TextBox

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    txtServers = formServers.txtServers
End Sub

Private Sub txtServers_LostFocus(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtServers.LostFocus
    ' ...
End Sub
```

The advantage of the latter approach, besides the more consistent, and possibly more elegant syntax, is that you don't have to remember to call `RemoveHandler`.

Comment: Great, that does that trick. Thanks for the explanation as well as the example.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it involves tighter coupling and is more fragile than exposing an event (as in Hans's example).  Changing `FormServers` implementation can break `Form1`.  Raising the event in `FormServers` decouples the implementation details and should be preferred.

Comment: @J... Agreed.  Hans had already posted a good explanation for a better design, in this particular case, but I felt that it was worthwhile to also post the actual technical answer to the question as asked.  I think that having controls be public by default was a mistake by MS in the first place.  There are times when inspecting another forms controls directly is necessary or important, but in most cases, you should treat them as private even when they are not, just out of principle.

Comment: @J... But there are many other situations, not involving controls, where another class properly exposes a public property which raises its own events.  In such cases, it is totally appropriate to use `WithEvents`.  It's one of the few niceties that VB.NET actually provides.  As long as we must live with all of the other terrible syntax issues that VB has, we might as well use and enjoy the few things it does better than other languages :)

Comment: @StevenDoggart Absolutely, exposing a property or event is fine and I agree it's the right way to do it.  Like Hans' example you can do `handles FormServers.ServersLeave` and that's great.  My only issue was with coupling to the texbox itself.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is fairly misleading.  The *Handles* keyword has several restrictions, it cannot work across different classes, it needs an object reference.  You must use the more universal *AddHandler* keyword instead.

There are some additional problems in your scenario.  Never use the LostFocus event, use Leave instead.  And it is very important that you subscribe the event for the specific instance of the form, using `As New` gets you into trouble when you display the form multiple times, an ObjectDisposedException will be the outcome.  Correct code looks like this:

```
Private formInstance As FormServers 

Private Sub DisplayFormServer()
    formInstance = new FormServers
    AddHandler formInstance.txtServers.Leave, AddressOf txtServers_Closing
    AddHandler formInstance.FormClosed, _
        Sub()
            formInstance = Nothing
        End Sub
    formInstance.Show()
End Sub
```

---

A much more elegant approach is to expose the event explicitly in your FormServers class.  Make that look like this:

```
Public Class FormServers
    Public Event ServersLeave As EventHandler

    Private Sub txtServers_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtServers.Leave
        RaiseEvent ServersLeave(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, the explanations really help. Could you possibly elaborate on why I should use `Leave` as opposed to `LostFocus` though?

Comment: LostFocus has an operating system bug that can cause deadlock, the MSDN article for WM_KILLFOCUS has the details.  And the event fires even when focus isn't actually lost, for example when a Validating event cancels the focus change.  The Leave event solves these problems.